# Erro ao instalar o Jboss forge

Tags: java, jboss, jdk

Estou tentando instalar o `forge` na minha máquina *(windows 10)* via prompt. porém ao executar o comando:

> C:\Users\Leonardo\Desktop\forge-distribution-2.20.1.Final-offline\forge-distribution-2.20.1.Final\bin\forge

Aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> ERROR: JAVA_HOME not found in your environment. Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation

Sendo que eu já configurei nas configurações avançadas do sistemas desse jeito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe o que fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui, bastei reiniciar o computador rs

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]